# Encrypted Communication for File I/O

Tags: c#, encryption, file-io

We have a requirement to encrypt all data that passes through our ASP.NET MVC application while in-flight and at rest.  For data persisted in the database, the design is straightforward:

```
[Browser]  <== SSL ==>  [Pres-Server]  <== SSL ==>  [App-Server]  <== Oracle NET encryption ==>  [Database]
```

- We are using SSL between the browser and presentation tier server.
- We are using SSL between the presentation tier server and the application server (app server uses WCF services).
- We are using encrypted Oracle connections between the application server and the database server.
- We are using Oracle encryption to encrypt the database.

Our app also stores uploaded files.  We are planning to store these files outside of the database (for performance and other management reasons).  I expect that the files will be stored in an encrypted file system (perhaps in a SAN).  My question is how to encrypt the communication between the application server and the file system where the files are stored?

```
[Browser]  <== SSL ==>  [Pres-Server]  <== SSL ==>  [App-Server]  <== ??? ==>  [File System]
```

I don't *think* that standard File i/o in Windows is encrypted.  Any suggestions on how to encrypt this communication channel?  The app tier code is C#.

Comment: This is an issue of the operating system and network setup, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question, I believe, will be to use IPsec to secure the communications between our App server and the server(s) that host the file system where uploaded files will be stored.

```
[Browser]  <== SSL ==>  [Pres-Server]  <== SSL ==>  [App-Server]  <== IPSec ==>  [File System]
```

An IPsec overview can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec.

Microsoft OS specific IPsec info can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb531150.aspx.

As a side note for anyone who stumbles across this, SMB 3 could be a viable solution for some environments.  See http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/05/03/smb-3-security-enhancements-in-windows-server-2012.aspx.

The OS requirements for SMB 3 are Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.  You can find a list of which Windows OS versions support which SMB versions at http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2013/10/02/windows-server-2012-r2-which-version-of-the-smb-protocol-smb-1-0-smb-2-0-smb-2-1-smb-3-0-or-smb-3-02-you-are-using.aspx.